# Make google calendar python API client use specific browser profile

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Trying the code in the quick start guide here, I find the code tries to open a google URL using some firefox browser profile

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

If it needs to use a browser, I would like it to use a specific browser profile.  How can I make it use that profile?

Alternatively, if I can prevent it from needing to use a browser at all, that would work too (I've already given it a credentials.json, but I guess I need some additional security credential to get access which can only be obtained using a real browser?).